# How to fix my Prepared Statement to give me data from the DB in my application?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have my Java program and I need to get data from my MYSQL DB,
I wrote this one out but its just sysout so getting data from my class and not using the Prepared Statement (I can delete the first 3 lines and it will work the same ) 
Could use some help to figure out how to get data from my DB and print it out

```
public void viewClientDetails(ClientsBean client) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connect.getConnection().prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * FROM mbank.clients WHERE client_id = ?");
        ps.setLong(1, client.getClient_id());
        System.out.println(client.getClient_id());
        System.out.println(client.getName());
        System.out.println(client.getType());
        System.out.println(client.getPhone());
        System.out.println(client.getAddress());
        System.out.println(client.getEmail());
        System.out.println(client.getComment());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Problem occurs while trying to see client details");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's Java, not JAVA. Also no need to write it in the title since it's tagged.

Comment: what do you expect? There is no execution of the query in your code. furthermore there is no resultset. Your code does the right thing :)

Comment: Just type this in your favourite search engine's text box and you will find the first link like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply not executing the query. Add a [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) call. And fetch the results from the returned [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

For example:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connect.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mbank.clients WHERE client_id = ?");
ps.setLong(1, client.getClient_id());    
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String userid = rs.getString("id");
    String username = rs.getString("name"); 
}
```

As @Jon Skeet pointed out, the declaration of `ResultSet` in Java 7 is updated to:

```
public interface ResultSet extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable
```

It is `AutoClosable` now, which means that you can and should use the [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Well you're not actually *executing* the prepared statement... you're just preparing it. You should call [`PreparedStatement.executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) and use the `ResultSet` it returns:

```
// ...code as before...
try (ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery()) {
    while (results.next()) {
        // Use results.getInt etc
    }
}
```

(You should use a try-with-resources statement to close the `PreparedStatement` too - or a manual `try/finally` block if you're not using Java 7.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do executeQuery on the preparedstatement to get a result set back of the query you performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the below.

```
 PreparedStatement ps = connect.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM mbank.clients WHERE client_id = ?");
 resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
 while (resultSet.next()) {
     String user = resultSet.getString("<COLUMN_1>");
     String website = resultSet.getString("<COLUMN_2>");
     String summary = resultSet.getString("<COLUMN_3>");
 }
```